# view fliper with intent passing

Tags: android

can  i pass intent in view flipper?
i m using 2 vlipper in same page and both have load different content but activity is same for all data?

```
//ViewFlipper vf1=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
ViewFlipper vf2=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper2);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
if(ViewFlipper==vf1){
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.branchlist, null);
    View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.year_list, null);
    View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.semester_list, null);
    vf1.addView(v1);
    vf1.addView(v2);
    vf1.addView(v3);
    vf1.showNext();
    vf1.showPrevious();
}
if(ViewFlipper==vf2){
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.branchlist, null);
    View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.semester_list, null);
    vf2.addView(v1);
    vf2.addView(v2);

    vf2.showNext();
    vf2.showPrevious();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by pass intent in View Flipper .. can you elaborate more on the functionality you want to achieve?